# SwiftUI: Navigation View/Bar/Link and ScrollView issues since iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, swiftui

Since iOS 14.5, the behaviour when pushing a new view onto a scrolled navigation view appears to have changed and no longer works the way it did on iOS 14.4

[Image of the differences here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEOmE.jpg)

On iOS 14.4, when pushing a new view onto a NavigationView via a NavigationLink, the new view renders (as expected) with the .large NavigationBar in it's expanded state.

On iOS 14.5, with the exact same code, the new view renders with the .large NavigationBar in either an expanded or collapsed state (with the content scrolled up) depending on the state from the parent view.
If you have scrolled the parent view, the navigation bar will be collapsed. If you have not scrolled the parent view the navigation bar will be expanded.
This is not the behaviour I want or expect. I expect the navigation bar on the child view to always be expanded.

Code below:

```
struct RootView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            ScrollView() {
                VStack() {
                    
                    Text("Root view")
                        .navigationTitle("Root")
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                        .padding()
                    
                    ForEach(0...50, id: \.self){ i in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination:DetailView(title: "Link \(i)")
                        ){
                            Text("Link \(i)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            VStack() {
                Text(title)
                    .navigationTitle("Detail")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                
                ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { x in
                    Text("Scroll content! \(x)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in how I set up the views?

Comment: What happens if you move the "navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)" modifier to a different node?

Comment: Same problem no matter where I place it from what I can tell. The thing that makes me _pause_ is that, it is still created as a .large, just it's collapsed by default. As in, it's not created as a .inline which it looks like at first, once you scroll it corrects itself

Comment: same issure, use `List` instead of `ScrollView` will looks better, but in detail view the NavigationLink will follow an arrow icon

Comment: Unfortunately a List is no use to me. The specific use case in my app requires a scroll view 